# Making a list of patterns of arbitrary length

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, pattern-matching

I would like to create a list of arbitrary length:

```
{x1_, x2_, ...}
```

Where each of the elements of the list has the full form:

```
Pattern[xi, Blank[]]
```

[This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/36887) shows how to create a list of symbols:

```
{x1, x2, ...}
```

but I don't know how to adapt that to obtain the above.

I intend to use this list in the definition of a function as in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95760/59896).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Array[ToExpression["x" <> ToString @ # <> "_"] &, {5}]
```

> {x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_}

```
FullForm @ %
```

> List[Pattern[x1,Blank[]], Pattern[x2, Blank[]], Pattern[x3, Blank[]], Pattern[x4, Blank[]], Pattern[x5, Blank[]]]

Also

```
Thread[Pattern[Evaluate@Array[Symbol["x" <> ToString@#] &, {5}], Blank[]]]
```

> {x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_}

and

```
ToExpression[Table["x" <> i <> "_", {i, ToString /@ Range[5]}]]
```

> {x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_}

Comment: The middle one will fail if `x1=1`.

Comment: @Kuba, good point.

Answer (score 8):

If you construct a list of strings instead, you can take advantage of the fact that [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression) is listable, and supports a 3rd argument that post-processes the output. For example:

```
ToExpression[
    {"x1", "x2", "x3"},
    StandardForm,
    Pattern[#,Blank[]]&
]
```

> {x1_, x2_, x3_}

Or, creating the list and converting:

```
ToExpression[
    Table["x" <> ToString@i, {i, 5}],
    StandardForm,
    Pattern[#, Blank[]]&
]
```

> {x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_}

Comment: It won't work if `x1 = 1`.

Comment: `Function[{sym},Pattern[sym,Blank[]],{HoldFirst}]` instead of `Pattern[#,Blank[]]&` as usual.

Comment: @Kuba what exactly do you mean by `x1 = 1` ?

Comment: @Winkelried if any of `xi` have values prior to that evaluation then you will get e.g. `Pattern[1, Blank[]]`

Answer (score 6):

Nothing new but shorter:

```
StringTemplate["x``_"] /@ Range[10] // ToExpression
```

> ```
> {x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_, x10_}
> ```

Comment: you did again. a quick, simple, short, and robust 1-liner holy grail of MMA. im 58. when i grow up i hope to master MMA as well you.

Comment: @JulesManson thanks for kind words, one liners are nice for a hands-on prototyping but in general I'd trade compactness for readability. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how to make the solution in the link work for this case:

```
patt = Table[
   With[
    {s = Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]]},
    Pattern[s, Blank[]]
    ], {i, 10}];

Range[10] /. patt :> {x5, x8}
```

> `{5, 8}`

Using `With` here is a trick to insert the symbol into `Pattern`. Since `Pattern` has the attribute `HoldFirst`, it would not work to write e.g.

```
Pattern[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], Blank[]]
```

because `Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]]` would not be evaluated before it was passed to `Pattern`, i.e. `Pattern` would not receive a string as is required.

Comment: It won't work if `x1 = 1`

Comment: @Kuba You mean if the symbols have values?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @Kuba Well, you are right. I wanted to show how to adapt the answer OP linked to, but it has this flaw.