# How to define constants in Mathematica like c1,c2,c3,...cn?

Tags: symbolic, expression-construction

Manually defining the constants is tedious if the 'n' is large. how to do this?

Comment: So, why not use a `List` to store those constants?

Comment: It may help you to read [this Q&A abount indexed variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94294/10397).

Comment: Closely related: [Making a list of patterns of arbitrary length](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/180763/5478)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 n = 10000; konstants = ToExpression /@ ("c" <> # & /@ (ToString /@ Range[n]))
```

Answer (score 10):

Have you considered using `c[1]..c[n]` instead of `c1..cn`? Then you can just use `constants = Array[c,n]` to generate them, and they're much easier to handle later in the calculation.

For example, you could define a polynomial like this:

```
p = c[0] + Sum[c[i]*x^i, {i,4}];
```

Then later evaluate it for some specific set of constants:

```
actualCoefficients = Range[5]
p /. { c[i_] :> actualCoefficients[[i+1]] }
```

You can also calculate derivatives:

```
D[p, c[1]]
```

or perform optimization over these values:

```
FindMinimum[costTerm, Array[c,5]]
```

Comment: This is even better. This solves the actual problem.  We can further do operations using these constants right?

Comment: Yes, you can usually use `c[1]` as a constant anywhere, just like `c1` - just make sure you don't define the symbol `c` anywhere.

Comment: Actually, there are a few differences, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94298/242 - but in practice, in my experience, using `c[...]` as constants in a calculation makes life much simpler

Answer (score 5):

```
With[ {n = 10},  
    Array[ 
        Symbol[ "c" <> ToString @ #]&
        , n
    ] 
]
```

> {c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10}

**Update**

Yes, usually using `c[1], c[2], ...` instead of `c1, c2, ...` is the better choice. Neverytheless, it must not be as cumbersome as it looks if we take up the examples provided by @Niki Estner:

```
indexedC = Array[ Symbol[ "c" <> ToString @ # ]&, 5 ];
(* {c0, c1, c2, c3, c4} *)
```

Then the polynomial given above can be constructed as follows:

```
p = Sum[ indexedC[[i]] x^( i - 1), {i, 5}];
```

And I do find the evaluation for `actualCoefficients` even clearer as Niki's pattern solution:

```
actualCoefficients = Range[5];
p /. Thread[ indexedC -> actualCoefficients ]
```

> $1 + 2 x + 3 x^2 + 4 x^3 + 5 x^4$

So it is not as bad as it looks and avoids the problems with `C[1]` being a DownValue instead of an OwnValue (see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94294/764)).